# Can somebody please explain to me why NPSPACE=PSPACE in a simple way?

Tags: computational-complexity

This is what I found on the web, but why is this true? Can somebody explain it as simply as possible, please?

In other words, if a nondeterministic Turing machine can solve a problem using f(n) space, an ordinary deterministic Turing machine can solve the same problem in the square of that space bound.

Comment: Have you found Savitch's Theorem on the web?

Comment: @Get In other words, if a nondeterministic Turing machine can solve a problem using f(n) space, an ordinary deterministic Turing machine can solve the same problem in the square of that space bound. But how is this proved?

Comment: So, you don't like the proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem#Proof ? or any of the links given at that page? http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/6420/spr16/Notes/PSPACE/savitch.html or https://youtu.be/VW1efHamKAs or https://youtu.be/mTsBA1c7yIw or https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse431/14sp/scribes/lec16.pdf

Comment: Or https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/the-crux-of-savitchs-theorem

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, Benny?

Comment: Are you still here, Benny?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah ty it helped me